# Unable to install pillow 6.2.1 in conda

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library, conda, torchvision

After upgrading `pytorch` / `torch-vision` the following error occurs:

```
python -c "import torch ; import torchvision as tv; print(torch.__version__, tv.__version__)
> "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pointr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from torchvision import datasets
  File "/home/pointr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .fakedata import FakeData
  File "/home/pointr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/fakedata.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import transforms
  File "/home/pointr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .transforms import *
  File "/home/pointr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import functional as F
  File "/home/pointr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, PILLOW_VERSION
ImportError: cannot import name 'PILLOW_VERSION' from 'PIL' (/home/pointr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

This has been noted as due to an incompatibility between `conda` and `pytorch 7.0.0`  https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1712 . So  I need to downgrade to `pillow 6.2.1`:

The command posted to do this is:  `conda install pillow=6.2.1 -y`

However that is failing:

```
 (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
```

That is hanging.  So now what ?   The workaround needs itself a workaround ..  Is `conda` broken for `torchvision` now?   The primary reason I am using `conda` in the first place is `torch` / `torchvision` ..

**Update** Conda tried to `resolve conflicts`. After 20 minutes of this it was 13% done. Ridiculous. This is a 2020 core i7 mini-tower. No sane program takes more than low double digits seconds to resolve dependencies.  I finally killed it.  I am going to try the suggestion to do directly from `pip`:

```
pip install Pillow==6.2.1
```

OK - that is *hanging* ..  I am going to uninstall `pillow` and reinstall it with that version.

**Another update**  @erip has recommended `conda install -c conda-forge pillow=6.2.1` - so here we go:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pillow=6.2.1
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
```

I will let the dust settle on that one but looking quite unlikely.

Comment: Conda and package installation always had conflicts and incompatibility. Would suggest installing it through `pip` as well and use the package directly from the global `site-packages`.

Comment: @JimitVaghela Do you have details on how to install directly from the global `site-packages` ?

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge pillow=6.2.1` should work. See [here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pillow).

Comment: @javadba : erip's answer does look promising. Try that out.

Comment: @erip  `Solving environment: failed` I will update the question

Comment: @JimitVaghela  Tried it out and updated the question

Comment: It looks like there's something corrupted in your environment. Perhaps it's worth trying to update your env or reinstalling.

Comment: @erinp  Yes - I did in fact do that - and posted a middling answer to that effect.

Comment: What other packages do you have in your environment? Are you installing all this in the base environment?

Comment: Yes all in the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me is to uninstall /  reinstall `conda`

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

And here are the versions `conda` elected to install:

```
(base) pointr@alienware:~/anaconda3$ python -c "import cv2; import PIL;print('cv2: ' + cv2.__version__); print('PIL: ' + PIL.__version__)"

cv2: 4.1.0
PIL: 7.1.2

(base) pointr@alienware:~/anaconda3$ python -c "import torch ; import torchvision as tv; print('torch:' + torch.__version__); print('torchvision: ' + tv.__version__)"

torch:1.3.1
torchvision: 0.4.2
```